# HDD doesn't boot despite being recognized on bios (uefi)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, bios, uefi

The only thing I did was disconnect physically the HDD(with the pc off of course) to check some info like the rpm, vendor, etc, but then I forgot to reconnect it and when I turned on my pc it only showed my the uefi menu (of course because the HDD was not connected). Realizing that I turned off the pc and reconnected the hdd, nevertheless it is still showing me the uefi menu, it recognizes the hdd but when I try to boot (using the boot menu) from the hdd the screen goes black and then it goes back to uefi.

Processor and RAM are also recognized.

My Motherboard is ASUS.
Bios version 0612 x64
Just in case my OS is Arch Linux and it is up to date.

**Edit 1:** Just tried the hdd in another pc(which from now on I'll call it the secondary pc). It didn't initiate, instead it shows me this:

[image]

**Edit 2:** I ran fdisk from an arch linux booteable usb, I got this:

[image]

Running fsck on the three partitions of my hdd:

[image]

However, running it on each partition separately(sda1, sda2, sda3 instead of just sda) it returns a message "clean" without any errors in all of them.

Also I scanned my hdd for possible bad blocks with the command `backblocks`, after 2 hours of scanning it returned me `Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)`

**Edit 3:** Disabling PXE, which in this pc(the secondary one) it is named as 'boot to network', and trying again to boot from the hdd results in this message: `A booteable device has not been detected, please refer to the product guide to http://support.intel.com/support/motherboard/desktop/`

In the main PC (the one in which the problem originated) this PXE option was already disabled, I tried enabling it and after rebooting it happens the same as in the first image (Edit 1). So the behaviour is the same in both my main pc and the secondary one:

**PXE enabled:** Causes a black screen as show in Edit 1, this happens in both, main and secondary pc's.
**PXE disabled:** Causes a black screen with the message I've already put in this edit, this happens in the secondary pc, in the main one the screen goes black for about 0.5 - 1 secs and then it gets back to the uefi menu.

**Edit 4:** I just tried mounting one of my hdd partition, the bigger one which have all the non-system files and directories, while using the Arch Linux booteable usb and I could perfectly navigate through all my data in the terminal, even visualize text files, I didn't try to modify any of them though, I didn't want to possible mess the hdd.

So these are good news, the data is intact it seems, is just that I can't access the system because for some reason my pc thinks my hdd is not a 'booteable device' despite it being listed in the boot options.

PD: My hdd have 3 partitions, a 500mb one for grub, a 50 gb for linux system itsef, and a 880 GB one for all my data.

Comment: Can you put the drive in a carrier and attach to another computer. Does it work in the other computer. That is the first thing I would try.

Comment: Your BIOS may have automatically re-organized your boot devices or even disabled that HDD as a boot device when it was missing. Recheck your boot config in your BIOS first.

Comment: Just tried connecting it in another pc it doesn't show me the bios but instead it seems it is trying to boot the hdd but it can't. I edited the question with a screenshoot.

Comment: @Layne Bernardo my uefi menu have an option to boot directly from a selected boot device, right now the only device that appears is the HDD but when I select it the screen goes black and after 0.5 sec aprox. it goes back to the uefi menu.

Comment: It appears from the screen shot that the drive may have developed a hardware issue.

Comment: Maybe try disabling network boot (iPXE) completely. It shouldn't be causing any problems but I have actually seen that on some BIOS's, where they won't boot properly from a disk when iPXE is enabled. It sounds like maybe there's some data corruption on the disk though, do you have another PC you could use to run `fdisk` on the drive?

Comment: @LayneBernardo I do, I'm currently connected in the other pc which have windows 10, but fdisk is a terminal program right? I guess I'll need a bootable usb

Comment: Correct, fdisk is a Linux terminal program so you will need to plug the HDD into a working Linux computer to run it. You can do this either with a bootable USB (probably the easiest) or if you have WSL installed on your Windows 10 PC you can use it within bash I believe, although I'm not sure how WSL handles physical drive access. If you're lucky, something just got corrupted somehow when you pulled the drive and fdisk can recover it. If not it might be time to look into data recovery.

Comment: @LayneBernardo I edited the question with the results of the fsdisk, fsck and badblocks commands. In the secondary PC, when I disable PXE (it is named as just 'boot to network', searching on google I found that this is the equivalent to PXE) it causes that when trying to boot the hdd a message appears saying `A booteable device has not been detected, please refer to the product guide to intel.com`.

Comment: Being the case that the bios recognizes my hdd(but not as a booteable device) and all my data seems to be intact(see my last edit), maybe the linux system partition or grub partition are the issue here? I was reading a bit and it seems that grub is in charge of connect the bios with the linux system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of a bootloader installation process in UEFI is storing that bootloader's exact filename from the "EFI System Partition" within the motherboard's NVRAM memory. The firmware doesn't boot the whole disk; it boots a specific file on that disk.

(There can be multiple bootloaders and each of them is stored as a separate boot entry, i.e. there's no fighting over which OS will get "the" MBR.)

When you boot with the disk disconnected, the firmware removes all entries referencing that disk, thinking that they're no longer valid, so later it no longer knows where your GRUB installation *is.*

If you have access to the EFI Shell, use it to manually run GRUB and boot Linux that way. Afterwards re-run `grub-install`.

```
fs0:
cd \efi\arch
dir
grubx64.efi
```

If not – then mount the EFI System Partition, create a directory `EFI\boot`, copy the grubx64.efi file there, then rename the file to `bootx64.efi`. The firmware will look in this exact location even if there's no boot entry pointing there.

Alternatively, as you have an Arch install USB, use `arch-chroot`
&c. then re-run `grub-install`.

Comment: Good advice, just a remark: Some EFI biosses like the path and EFI filename to be all lower-case, others are not case-sensitive and again others want the case to be exactly as stored on disk.

Comment: Something weird happend to the last line of your answer. Did you intent a &c ?

Comment: When you say "If you have access to the EFI Shell" you are refering to the EFI shell from my hdd, right? Because when booting from the arch usb there is an option called EFI shell, this one is not what you are refering to, right?

Comment: Just reinstalled grub using the arch booteable usb and everything is fine again, I want to thank you for clarifying the nature of the issue and sending me in the right direction.

Comment: @Tonny Even weirder, some older BIOS's (especially HP) will ONLY boot `\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi`. This is mostly from computers made around the time that EFI was first becoming an accepted boot standard, and it's a huge pain if you want to dual boot on one of those PCs.

Comment: @LayneBernardo I know. (Don't get me started....) For HP computers with that problem a Bios upgrade usually fixes that. Of course provided you can get it to boot from a USB stick to start with. Some of those same machines would only boot USB in EFI mode, while the Bios update required CSM...

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of incorrect BIOS settings. Please post your BIOS screens: where boot devices are selected and in which order they are searched, where BIOS is listing connected HDDs, and where are special HDD optiones mentioned.
You always have an option to boot from any liveCD (USB or DVD if you have one) and check your partitions and especially boot flag (that markes the partition bootablable for BIOS).